# Enterprise Library Logging - Always logging using the defaultCategory and not respecting the categorySources defined in web.config

Tags: web-config, enterprise-library, logging-application-block

MSEL 5 has been working like a charm for us, but off late I have been trying to configure additional "categorySources" but the result is always the same.  The log entry is always made using the "defaultCategory" and the following error is logged in the log file **"Message: There is no explicit mapping for the categories 'AppLogGen'. The log entry was: "**

The web.config "loggingConfiguration" entry

```
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="AppLog">
<listeners>
  <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    fileName="c:\LoggingTrace\trace.log" formatter="Text Formatter"
    rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Midnight" rollSizeKB="10000"
    timeStampPattern="dd-MM-yyyy" traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" />
  <add name="Flat File Trace Listener Login" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    fileName="c:\LoggingTrace\traceLogin.log" formatter="Text Formatter Login"
    rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Midnight" rollSizeKB="10000"
    timeStampPattern="dd-MM-yyyy" traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" />
</listeners>
<formatters>
  <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    template="Format 1:: Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;"
    name="Text Formatter" />
  <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    template="Format 2:: Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;"
    name="Text Formatter Login" />
</formatters>
<categorySources>
  <add switchValue="All" name="InfinityWeb">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </add>
  <add switchValue="All" name="AppLog">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Flat File Trace Listener Login" />
    </listeners>
  </add>
  <add switchValue="All" name="AppLogGen">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Flat File Trace Listener Login" />
    </listeners>
  </add>
</categorySources>
<specialSources>
  <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
  <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
  <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </errors>
</specialSources>
```

The code, writing to the log file

```
            //logWriter.Write(message, category, priority, eventId, (TraceEventType)severity, DefaultTitle, null);
        LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
        logEntry.Categories.Add("AppLogGen");
        logEntry.Message = "Override " + message;

        logWriter.Write(logEntry);
```

The ouput in the log file

```
Timestamp: 9/6/2012 1:15:23 PM
```

Message: There is no explicit mapping for the categories 'AppLogGen'. The log entry was:

Timestamp: 9/6/2012 7:45:23 AM

Message: Override Login successful for UserId:Admin

Category: AppLogGen

Severity: Information
Category: AppLog
.
.
.
Extended Properties:

**Irrespective of what I do, the logging always uses the category source specified in "defaultCategory".  Already spent two days on this one.  Help!**

Comment: I really can't see anything wrong here.  Where is this running, it couldn't be a case where the changes aren't getting deployed?  Also, are you using the configuration tool to make the edits?  That will ensure everything is properly formatted and less likely to have mistakes.

Comment: This is running off a web server.  I know that changes are being deployed, because 1. I am directly modifying the web.config 2. Everytime I update the defaultCategory, the same is correctly used to log the entry.  Also tried using the configuration tool; same result.

Comment: Perhaps adding a name to the configuration might help?  I have no reason to believe that it would, but I've never seen one without it and that is all I can see that is different from what I would do.

Comment: Hey Tushax, were you ever able to find the issue with this? I'm experiencing the exact same thing still.

Comment: @gitsitgo No solution yet.  The same configuration works great (or even better) for four other Windows apps but not for the web app.

Answer (score 0):

```
<allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
    <listeners>
      <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
```

These lines of code have the issue. "Flat File Trace" Listener is the default listener for all events. so whatever event would happen would be listen by default listner.
You should check by commenting this listener.

Comment: Please delete your answer if you want to remove the content.